# Error fetching HTTP headers when connecting to UPS API via PHP SoapClient

Tags: php, wsdl, http-headers, ups

About 1.5 years ago I have written an integration with UPS (United Parcel Service) that generates shipping labels. I have stopped using UPS in January and am now coming back to this integration.

Recently I've been constantly seeing "**error fetching http headers**" on almost every other request I make to the UPS API. Their production server returns this error usually every other request (but when it does, it keeps doing it 2-3 times in a row), and their development server returns this error constantly. My requests are reasonably spaced (at least 10 seconds apart).

The application is written in **PHP (v5.3.28)** and uses **SoapClient** with UPS' WSDL forms.

From the experience of others with similar problems, it looks like it has something to do with UPS not wanting to keep a connection alive and my server persisting it for some reason.

So far I've tried:

- increasing the default_socket_timeout and max_execution_time
- passing keep_alive = 0 and high value connection_timeout to the constructor of the SoapClient
- writing a wrapper around the SoapClient to destroy the connection right after a __call() and __soapCall()
- turning off HTTP Keep-Alive in IIS' common headers (please don't judge)

I'm running out of ideas on how to approach this problem or even where to continue diagnosing it. It seems that most people on SO were able to solve their issues with increasing the socket_timeout, but that did not help me.

Any pointers are appreciated.

// EDIT

I've figured it out. I was able to talk an admin into upgrading to PHP 5.6 and with this piece of code, I was able to solve the problem:

```
$client = new SoapClient("wsdl_goes_here", array(
            'keep_alive' => 0,
            'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
            'trace' => 1,
            'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
                'ssl' => array(
                    'verify_peer' => false,
                    'verify_peer_name' => false
                )
            ))
        ));
```